# How to extend continous function from $S^1\to S^1$ to $D^2\to D^2$ continously

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:S^1\to S^1$ is the continous map then I have to prove that there exist continous extension $\bar f$ of f such that  $\bar f:D^2\to D^2 $ is continous map  where $D^2$ is closed disc in $\mathbb R^2$

I had following idea .

we can map origin to origin.then suppose there is ray emaniting form origin to some point a, its image is ray emaniting form origin to f(a) and same will follows.

But I could not able to write explicit form of function.

Is my idea is correct? Can anyone please help me how to write explicitly map.

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to use polar coordinates. We think of $f$ as a continuous periodic function $f(\theta)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $[0,2\pi]$). Then define a function on $D^2$ by
$$\overline{f}(r,\theta)=rf(\theta)$$
where $0<r\leq 1$ and $0\leq\theta \leq 2\pi$. Also define it at the origin by $\overline{f}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$D^2$ is the cone of $S^1$, that is, it is homeomorphic to the quotient of $S^1\times [0,1]$ where you collapse $S^1\times \{0\}$ to a single point, and in this model the inclusion $S^1\to D^2$ is just the inclusion $S^1\to S^1\times \{1\}$.

This gives a straightforward way of extending these maps : write an element of $D^2$ as $r z$ with $z\in S^1, r\in [0,1]$ and define $\overline{f}(rz) := rf(z)$.

If you don't know about the above homeomorphism, you can try to prove it, or you can check the continuity by hand, it's not hard.